# Page has_many images, how to have user add an image to this page in a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is somewhat related to my other question but slightly different.

So on each page, I have an Add Image button that pops up a modal window with a form to add an image with its title and description. However, I am unsure about how to have it so that it automatically uses the page_id of the page that it's on.

The form so far is:

```
<%= form_for @image do |f| %>

  <%= f.label 'Image URL:' %>
  <%= f.text_field :source %>

  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>

  <%= f.label :description %>
  <%= f.text_field :description %>

  <%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

Is there a way to have the image.page_id to be set to that page's id when the image is created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use nested routes, so in your routes.rb you will have:

```
resources :pages do
  resources :images
end
```

then you have url helpers to create an add link:

```
<%= link_to 'add image', new_page_image_path(@page) %>
```

it creates a path like `/pages/:page_id/images/new` which is routed to the action `new` of controller `ImagesController` with a params[:page_id] set to `@page.id`

In your `ImagesController` extend the new action to

```
def new
  @image= Image.new(page_id: params[:page_id])
end
```

and put a hidden `page_id` in your form to preserve it during editing:

```
<%= form_for @image do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :page_id %>
  ...
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

You can use any JS to convert the link to a model window showing the image form.

Comment: That's a nifty idea. I will look into it. Thanks!